# Regarding code signing certificate in Installshield

Tags: certificate, installshield, code-signing

I came across very little literature to use code signing certificates without a private key being exported. Hence, requesting some basic info regarding including the code signing certificate in the installshield 2013 to sign our setup.exe file. 
So it goes like this... 
We had a certificate from Symantec and/or Verisign that expired a few days ago. So we got a new certificate from them which is a SHA-256 cert. However, they won't release the private key. Hence we cannot generate a .pfx file which used to include in our installshield. They say that, here on who ever wants to do the code signing using installshield needs the dongle attached to the computer to get the private key verification done. I don't quite understand what they mean. However, it is clear that they want us to connect with the dongle for private key verification. So if I do not have the pfx file, how can I achieve code signing using installshield 2013? I also read on the Web that the support for SHA-256 certs was not available in 2013 and that one would have to migrate to 2015 or above to do something of that sort. So we have hit a roadblock with this thing and our automated build process is failing. 
Hence, request you to provide me any pointers as to how can we get this thing done. 
Thanks and Regards, 
Bhushan.

Comment: "...However, they won't release the private key..." You are confused. They don't have the private key, you do.

Comment: @JamesKPolk... Confused is what I certainly am. Is there a way I can create a private key for the certificate at my end? What do I need to do exactly to generate a private key then? How did the .pfx with public and private keys exported work for us earlier? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

InstallShield 2015 or so added support for signing using certificates from certificate stores. Before that, some people have [intercepted the call to signtool](https://community.flexerasoftware.com/archive/index.php?t-218163.html), implementing their own calls to either the real signtool or the APIs it calls. This should give you the freedom to use your dongle-based private key, or anything else you need.

(On the downside, InstallShield 2015's and later implementation doesn't let you do this interception trick.)

Answer (score 0):

Ok...So it goes like this...We have a rights issue. As per Symantec, only the person who is the owner of the certificate, can generate a private key on his machine with his admin privileges and that too using IE 11 browser. Now the issue is, the certificate request goes to a helpdesk portal, pending an approval and then forwarded to symantec after the necessary approval. Looks like the approver has to act as the owner, even though the requesting team has paid for the certificate. That is weird but true. So the person who receives all the certificates first hand has to download the certificate, export the certificate along with the private key into the .pfx file and then send us the .pfx! Meanwhile, is there any possibility that I run the export certificate wizard from the browser and the export .pfx option is disabled just because the user launched the browser with insufficient privileges? How may I confirm that this is a rights issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Further to these, I simply have a very general question about signing. The thing is, even though I know what code signing is and some of the applications might absolutely need it, I do not see a substantial need for the windows based desktop applications. I may be wrong on this. However, all the literature I see points to the fact that the authority that is publishing should be trusted. Now we as a team are responsible for a suite of desktop applications that are being packaged using installshield and code signed by Symantec SHA 256 class certificates. We only sign the set.exe file and as a result it shows a typical trust prompt to the user who installs our software. Our users are a rather closely knit group of clients and are easily approachable. Also, I do not see a risk of our network being intercepted and hacked to tamper the content of setup. In such a situation, is having a certificate justified?
I have a few questions with respect to SignTool as well. I understand that the signing for our certificate is currently failing because we have not yet procured the private key for it. However, the timestamp verification is also failing for a self signed certificate that I have generated for testing purposes. So I need to understand what exactly is a timestamp doing in installshield when Signtool is invoked? Installshield is a good product; however the supporting documentation provided by Flexera is rather pathetic. Thanks.